# Managing Single User's Multiple Sessions and Expiring AccessToken Based on Session Usage in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core Web API project and currently faced with the challenge of managing multiple sessions for a single user across different browsers/devices. Additionally, I want to implement a mechanism where the AccessToken becomes invalid if it is not used for the session it was created for, basically the main objective is make accesstoken not usable if it compromised.

Here are some specific points I'm seeking guidance on:

**Handling Multiple Sessions:** How can I effectively manage multiple sessions for a single user, especially when they access the application from different browsers or devices? Is there a way to uniquely identify and manage these sessions?

**AccessToken Validity Based on Session:** I want to make the AccessToken associated with a specific session and invalidate it if it is not used for that session. What is the best way to implement this behavior? Should I include session information as a claim in the AccessToken?

**Revoking AccessToken:** In case a user logs out or their session becomes invalid for some reason, how can I ensure that the associated AccessToken becomes invalid as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Handling Multiple Sessions

#### 1. Generate and Store Unique Session Identifiers:

- When a user logs in or accesses your application, generate a unique
  session identifier.
- Store this session identifier in a database or a distributed cache
  along with user-related information.

#### 2. Validate Session Identifier on Each Request:

- On each request, validate the session identifier from the incoming
  request against the stored session identifiers.
- If the session identifier is not valid or not present, consider the
  session as unauthorized.

### AccessToken Validity Based on Session:

#### 1. Include Session Information in AccessToken Claims:

- When generating an AccessToken, include the session identifier as a
  claim.
- On each API request, validate the session identifier from the
  AccessToken against the stored session identifiers.

#### 2. Refresh AccessToken on Session Renewal:

- If a session is renewed or extended, consider refreshing the
  AccessToken to include the updated session information.

### Revoking AccessToken:

#### Maintain a Token Blacklist:

- When a user logs out or their session becomes invalid, add the
  AccessToken to a token blacklist.
- Check the token blacklist on each API request to ensure the
  AccessToken is not in the blacklist.